# Orthogonal and closedness in normed spaces with inner product

Tags: functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples, inner-products

Given a normed vector space $X$ such that the norm can be derived from an inner product ( pre Hilbert space ) and $S\subset X$ a subspace of $X$, then generally $\overline{S}\neq S ^{\bot\bot}.$ Also in general, $\overline{S}\oplus S ^{\bot}\neq X. $

I am wondering if the case $S=\{(x,y)|x, y \in R^2, x>0\}\subset R^2$ is a good example of the first situation ? Can you give some other examples ? How about examples for the second situation ?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: $S=\{(x,y)|x, y \in R^2, x>0\}$ is not a subspace of $ \mathbb R^2$ !

Comment: You must go infinite-dimensional to get your examples.

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1980777/is-there-a-subset-m-of-inner-product-space-u-such-that-m-bot-bot-i?rq=1 the answer there shows a subset $S$ with $\bar S\oplus S^\perp\ne X$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a subset $M$ of inner product space $U$ such that $(M^{\bot})^{\bot}$ is not the minimal closed subspace that contains $M$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1980777/is-there-a-subset-m-of-inner-product-space-u-such-that-m-bot-bot-i)

Answer (score 1):

As an example of the second situation, take $X$ as the set of all sequences $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of real numbers such that $n\gg1\implies a_n=0$. Consider the inner product$$\bigl\langle(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N},(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\bigr\rangle=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nb_n.$$Let$$S=\left\{(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\in X\,\middle|\,\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{n^2}=0\right\}.$$and note that $S\neq X$. Then $S^\perp=\{0\}$ and therefore $S\oplus S^\perp\neq X$.

Comment: Thanks.  What is meant by $n\gg1
$.

Comment: @user249018 It means “if $n$ is much bigger than $1$”.

Comment: What do you mean by $H$ ?

Comment: @user249018 It was a typo. I meant $X$.

Comment: Can we resume the condition $n\gg1\implies a_n=0
$ by saying that for only finitely many $n, a_n\neq 0 ?$

Comment: @user249018 Indeed you can. It's the same thing. It's just a matter of taste.

Comment: Will the condition $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{n}=0 $ also work ?

Comment: Yes, it will work.